# How to see a whole message in status bar in vim?

Tags: message

I am using YCM plugin for Vim. And sometimes error messages are too long and I do not see them whole (see Fig.).
[image]
So how to expand (temporarly) the status bar in Vim or there is another way to see full message?

Comment: Do they show up in [`:messages`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#%3Amessages)?

Comment: I ran into the same sort of issue as you a bit back and I remember that Valloric actually [said](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/415#issuecomment-22042254) you can't do that (or at least not from their end). Don't know if you can redirect it somewhere so you can read it though

Comment: @muru, Seems they are not in messages.

Answer (score 18):

From the YCM documentation.

> YCM will display a short diagnostic message when you move your cursor
>   to the line with the error. You can get a detailed diagnostic message
>   with the `<leader>d` key mapping (can be changed in the options) YCM
>   provides when your cursor is on the line with the diagnostic.
>
> You can also see the full diagnostic message for all the diagnostics
>   in the current file in Vim's `locationlist`, which can be opened with
>   the `:lopen` and `:lclose` commands (make sure you have set let
>   `g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1` in your vimrc). A good way to
>   toggle the display of the locationlist with a single key mapping is
>   provided by another (very small) Vim plugin called ListToggle (which
>   also makes it possible to change the height of the `locationlist`
>   window), also written by yours truly.