# YouCompleteMe messages truncated

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I'm using YouCompleteMe for syntax checking, and long error messages at the bottom of the screen are truncated. How can I view the full message?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Are those error messages about your code syntax or the plugin logs?

Comment: They're for the code syntax

Comment: ycm does syntax checking now??? in any case, you might be able to use the quickfix/location list commands

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

- [How to see a whole message in status bar in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13795/how-to-see-a-whole-message-in-status-bar-in-vim)
- https://ycm-core.github.io/YouCompleteMe

for me, `<leader>d` or `\d` did the trick. There are other options such as `:YcmDiags` and decreasing terminal font size.